# Is there a way to have a range to auto sort when values are added in that range?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to create code to sort a range in `column A` after new info is added. I have tried this code but it is not working properly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("A1").Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

Comment: "not working properly" is not a great description of what's happening when your code runs.

Comment: nothing happened at all. i found this code online and it tries to run but states "Name argument not found".  code below                        {Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Column = 1 Then
   
   Dim lastrow As Long
   lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).ROW
   Range("A2:A15" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("A2:A15" & lastrow), Order1:=xlAscending, Headrer:=xlNo
   End If
   
   
    
End Sub}

Comment: never mind.... it was a type-o

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
   Dim lastrow As Long
   If Target.Column = 1 Then


       lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).ROW
       Range("A2:A15" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("A2:A15" & lastrow), _
                                  Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this an answer or?

Comment: `Range("A2:A15" & lastrow)` or `Range("A2:A" & lastrow)`  ?